# Why did Obi-Wan raise his hands to warn Luke in Dagobah?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back

In the movie *Star Wars The Empire Strikes Back* (1980), in the scene where Luke is loading cases into the X-fighter's underbelly before leaving Dagobah to save his friends, Obi-Wan Kenobi raises his hands and instructs Luke: "Don't give in to hate. That leads to the dark side". Both hands have their pinky fingers apart. In addition to attract the attention of Luke, was the old Jedi performing or indicating something with his hands lifted up in that manner?

Curiously, Sir Alec Guinness made a similar hand gesture few years earlier while performing Jacob Marley's Ghost in *Scrooge* (1970).

[image: Still image from Empire Strikes Back]

[image: Still image from Scrooge 1970]

Comment: It’s just a gesture. You might as well ask why Yoda pointed at something when he was talking about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot find a good reference... or article.

As a native English speaker. Both hands raised up in the way that Obi-Wan raises his hands means "Stop" or possibly "Slow down."

He is using his hands to emphasize/repeat the words that he is saying.